# Coordinate-wise gradient descent converges to least-squares solution

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, gradient-descent

Does somebody know a reference (or maybe short proof/argument) for the following claim:

Coordinate-wise gradient descent converges to a least-squares solution.

Coordinate-wise gradient descent: chooses at each iteration the component (coordinate) of a pre-specified design matrix for which the gradient (of the squared error loss function) is maximum. Then estimates the gradient via least-squares and proceeds along this estimate of the negative gradient.

Comment: Gradient descent involves an unspecified cost function. Without specifying the cost function, this assertion is not necessarily true. Are you using the sum of square residuals, or something proportional, as your cost?

Comment: The cost function are the sum of squared residuals.

Comment: The gradient method converges when it cannot step in any direction to make the cost function smaller. I believe its equivalent to that point being the least solution.

Comment: Assuming an appropriate step size and number of steps, stepping should result in minimizing the cost. If the cost is the sum of square residuals then there is one minimum so there is no reason to think that gradient descent should not converge to that minimum.